# Solve differential equation $y'' = -a y +\frac by$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve for y(t):
$$y'' =-ay + \frac by$$
I have tried a lot, but haven't succeeded so far. Actually I am not sure there is a 'nice' solution. Do any of you have ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Try multiplying the equation by $y'$. Note that then both sides can be written as a derivative.

Comment: I have tried. You 'll find: $$y' = \sqrt {2b Log[y] - a y^2 + constant}$$ And I haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: That equation is separable, and is solved with an integral. The resulting integral looks intractable, and your solution will be in implicit form (tricky integral in $y$ equals $x$), but so be it. Life can be tough when you're dealing with ODEs.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting $y'=p(y)$

Then $y''=\frac{d}{dx}(y')=p'_x=p'_yy'=p'p$

Then your equation is $p'p=-ay+\frac{b}{y}$, where $y$ is considered independent.